# Invite Friends Notification is not showing on facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, invite

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
appId:'my_app_id',
cookie:true,
status:true,
xfbml:true
});

function FacebookInviteFriends()
{
FB.ui({
method: 'apprequests',
message: 'http://www.librify.com'
});
}
</script>
//HTML Code
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<a href='#' onclick="FacebookInviteFriends();"> 
Facebook Invite Friends Link
</a>
```

this code is successfully sent invites but on `facebook notifications` invites is not showing.
Anything else required in this code for showing notification on facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your app->setting->add platform->App on Facebook.
Then fill-up Canvas URL and Secure Canvas URL. And then invite you friends again and enjoy.